# urlfetch unable to fetch URL in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

this question has been asked before but found no answers that worked !

i am using urlfetch in my code to fetch url content but am getting unable to fetch URL error . Heres a part of my code :

```
import cgi
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch   

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(MAIN_PAGE_HTML) # MAIN_PAGE_HTML is defined ..
class Hunt(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def flip(self):
       page=urlfetch.fetch('http://103.4.253.46/search?q=nexus 4')

#<////Rest Of the Code     /////>
```

i am getting Internal Server Error and this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~dime-hunt/1.371847514565231627/hunt.py", line 61, in post
    self.flip()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~dime-hunt/1.371847514565231627/hunt.py", line 39, in flip
    page=urlfetch.fetch('http://103.4.253.46/search?q=nexus 4')
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 270, in fetch
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 612, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 403, in _get_fetch_result
    raise DownloadError("Unable to fetch URL: " + url + error_detail)
DownloadError: Unable to fetch URL: http://103.4.253.46/search?q=nexus 4
```

i replaced the website name with the ipaddress but still the same error .
i am able to fetch data from the site using requests while testing locally in IDLE .

Comment: is it because you have a space between nexus and 4 instead of '%20'?

Comment: @Back2Basics strange but it worked !!! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'http://103.4.253.46/search?q=nexus%204'
```

replacing space by %20 solved the error as suggested by @Back2Basics